# Proving $\mathbb{E}\max\{\xi^2,\eta^2\}\leq 1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, average, correlation

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be random variables and $\mathbb{E}\xi=\mathbb{E}\eta=0$ also $\mathbb{D}\xi=\mathbb{D}\eta=1$. Here $\rho=\rho(\xi,\eta)$ is a correlation coefficient. Need to show $$\mathbb{E}\max\{\xi^2,\eta^2\}\leq 1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$$

So, I know that $\rho=\rho(\xi,\eta)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(\xi-\mathbb{E}\xi)(\eta-\mathbb{E}\eta)} {\sqrt{\mathbb{D}\xi \mathbb{D}\eta}}$.

But how to start and what qualities to use?

Comment: Assuming $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expected value. What is $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is a dispersion

Comment: So $\mathbf{D}$ is the square root of the second centred moment: $\mathbf{D}(X) = \mathbf{E}(X - \mathbf{E}(X))$?

Comment: Here is $\mathbb{D}X=\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2$